# A popup window, appears saying : script.googleusercontent.com says error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am developing a web app, with google apps script,  using google sheets as database,  linking 10 different pages html, and sometimes in my web app this message appears in a popup window, script.googleusercontent.com says error

reason or explanation